# Tag testcases in ReadyAPI

Tags: groovy, soapui, ready-api

I'm using ReadyAPI version 3.20.2 and I can't figure out how to add tags to my test cases. I need to execute only some tests in our staging environment and my first thought was to tag these testcases "staging".

According to documentation: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/ui/suite.html it should work.

But when I select my testsuite, the tag icon is greyed out.

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out how to add tags.

1. Select your testsuite
2. Click on Tag icon (next to garbage bin)
3. Enter name of your tag
4. Select testcase
5. Click on Tag icon and select your tag